# What are the pros and cons of each mashup baselayer?

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, google-maps, web-mapping, bing-maps

I've been making some mashups recently in OpenLayers and find myself naturally favouring OpenStreetMap as a baselayer, I think this is mostly because I like the concept. I realised the other day that I didn't really know why I prefered it, and have played about with googles various base layers, andlong with those of Yahoo and Bing.

Are there any discernible benefits of any of the baselayers that I have mentioned (or any others that I havent)? Do you find any problems with any of them or do you find that your users prefer one above the rest?

Comment: @Mapperz I'm not sure that it is "primarily opinion-based". I was asking for factual benefits and factual incidents of users preferring one baselayer. I was careful not to frame the question to ask for opinions

Comment: Well are you asking about cartographic visualisation of the map tiles or the quality of the underlying data? MapQuest Open is the same data as OSM but visually different.

Comment: I was asking about both, and also and technical/performance issue. On the visualisation front the facts of what sort of functionality each map was designed for. I think an answer to this question would allow stack exchange users to make better informed decisions as to which map to use. I'm asking for the facts that inform opinion rather than the opinion itself

Comment: @Mapperz and if you still disagree, where would you recommend I ask this question?

Comment: and is it any different to this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33918/should-i-use-openlayers-or-leaflet