# Is project more Leaflet or OpenLayers or Map Server friendly?

Tags: openlayers-2, leaflet, openlayers

I have several tables in a database on PostGIS.

I want to create a website where the users can log-in, show the layers they want and filter the elements of the layers based on the fields of the layers.

I want to create a very friendly interface for the users to filter the layers.
I mean just boxes to check and limits of interval to set.

Based on this description, I would say that OpenLayers is better but on the other hand, the numerous community around Leaflet makes me think that the support is better with Leaflet.

Moreover, I just started learning HTML/CSS and I know barely nothing about JavaScript but learning is not trouble for me. I love it and I will need to improve my web development skills anyway (for another project).

I have seen [Choosing OpenLayers or Leaflet?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33918) but it dates from 3 years ago at least and I am wondering if Leaflet hasn't solved its cons. For example OpenStreetMap changed from OpenLayers to Leaflet.

Comment: I had seen it, but I lack knowledge to judge on my own which one to choose. Moreover the post is getting old.

Comment: Leaflet is good for small projects only displaying few information (e.g. some shops on a store locator) or if you have multiple maps on a page. It's core is small (fast loading times), but it has many plug-ins. Some of them are not well-maintained.

OpenLayers is the way to go for feature-rich web apps such as yours, I'd say, where loading times are not an issue, but the map is the main feature of the page.

Comment: The only huge advantage that comes to my mind of OpenLayers over Leaflet is it's capability of combining/displaying layers with different CRS in the same map.

Comment: The age of the original is never a reason to ask a duplicate question. Even if that one had not been asked, this one seeks to compare three products and thus lacks focus. It also seeks opinions.